# How can I escape single or double quotation marks in CSS?

Tags: html, css, parsing, escaping, quotes

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="working">Touch Me!</div>
<div id="notworking">Don't Touch Me!</div>
```

And I have this CSS:

```
#working:hover:after{
    content: "Nice Touch";
    color: #0C6;
}
#notworking:hover:after{
    content: "I Said Don't Touch Me";
    color: #C30;
}
```

This code is working fine (my example is here): 
http://jsfiddle.net/gchoken/NaEPq/

My problem is that when I use double quotes for `"I Said Don't Touch Me"`, I get a warning.

CSS:

```
#notworking:hover:after{
    content: ""I Said Don't Touch Me"";
    color: #C30;
}
```

Warning message:

```
Warning: Found unclosed string '";'.
```

So, how exactly can I escape single or double quotes in CSS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a backslash.

```
content:"i said don\"t Touch me";
```

Same goes for single quotes within single-quoted strings.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/MUEVL)

Answer (score 3):

Just use a `\` to escape the `"`

```
#notworking:hover:after{
    content:"i said don\"t Touch me";
        color: #C30;
}
```

Demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/NaEPq/4/